# CSS Background Animation without a separate background wrapper

Tags: css

I am animating a background to move but as expected using `Background-position` results in poor performance.

I am unable to alter or change the HTML or add any scripts

I have attempted using `translate` but this moves the entire div element rather than just the background, As mentioned I am not able to create a separate div for the background alone resulting in this roadblock.

```css
.wm-outer-div {
  width: auto !important;
  min-width: 400px !important;
  max-width: 500px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.45) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 18px 22px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 304px;
  color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  font-family: walkme-opensans, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-collapse: inherit;
  background-image: none;
  line-height: normal;
  height: 300px;
  text-indent: inherit;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: medium;
  transition: none 0s ease 0s;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  direction: ltr;
  z-index: 2147483632;
  opacity: 1;
}

.wm-outer-div:after {
  content: "" !important;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  background-color: #1E365E !important;
  background-image: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrzzbsa5b39w8ra/image.jpg dl=1") !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  animation: slide 120s linear infinite  !important;
  repeat: repeat !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
}

@keyframes slide {
   from {
     transform: translateY(0);
   }
   to { 
     transform: translateY(-187%);
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="wm-outer-div wm-shoutout wm-shoutout-165013 wm-template-bg wm-template-small-corner wm-ltr wm-chrome wm-design-template-207418 wm-position-center" id="wm-shoutout-165013"></div>
```

Is there a way to target the background image separately to use `translate` without the addition of another div/wrapper so only the background moves and not the entire div element?

Failing that is there another option that could improve the performance of the background animation?

Comment: use pseudo element as your background layer and you can consider translate

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am not familiar with pseudo-elements, are you able help suggest how this could be done? I have added the HTML of the div in question that I have been applying CSS styles to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the pseudo element bigger to be sure you will cover the needed area when translating:

```css
.wm-outer-div {
  min-width: 400px !important;
  max-width: 500px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.45) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 18px 22px 20px;
  width: 304px;
  color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 0;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wm-outer-div:after {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #1E365E !important;
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpyrV.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300% ;
  height: 300%;
  animation: slide 2s linear infinite alternate;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes slide {
   from {
     transform: translateY(33%);
   }
   to { 
     transform: translateY(-33%);
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="wm-outer-div wm-shoutout wm-shoutout-165013 wm-template-bg wm-template-small-corner wm-ltr wm-chrome wm-design-template-207418 wm-position-center" id="wm-shoutout-165013"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wm-outer-div {
  width: auto !important;
  min-width: 400px !important;
  max-width: 500px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.45) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 18px 22px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 304px;
  color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  font-family: walkme-opensans, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-collapse: inherit;
  background-image: none;
  line-height: normal;
  height: 300px;
  text-indent: inherit;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: medium;
  transition: none 0s ease 0s;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  direction: ltr;
  z-index: 2147483632;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden
}
.wm-outer-div:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/c3phl1TZgQ92bLQugItmtovLZhs=/fit-in/1600x0/https://public-media.si-cdn.com/filer/54/10/5410da58-2295-4e3a-a847-fecd41cdcdd9/scarlet_tanager.jpg") !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-150px) translateY(150px)
}
```

```html
<div class="wm-outer-div wm-shoutout wm-shoutout-165013 wm-template-bg wm-template-small-corner wm-ltr wm-chrome wm-design-template-207418 wm-position-center" id="wm-shoutout-165013"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this separated the background image although when trying to animate the movement of the image using `transform` it doesn't show the remainder of the image and just cuts off any overflow. Resulting in white space being left behind? I updated my question to show the updated .CSS